# Bounty on adobe AIR Ubuntu 10.10 question

Tags: discussion, bounty

I see that there is a bounty on [a question about installing adobe AIR on Ubuntu 10.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11570/how-do-i-install-adobe-air-using-ubuntu-software-centre)

The description reads: "The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes."

I don't understand what the bounty is for. Does he want to update the question so it works for Ubuntu 13.10/12.04? Because that answer is already given in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371767/how-can-i-install-adobe-air-on-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10).

Also: Do I get the bounty if I edit one of the original answers or only if i add a new answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, newer answer, most likely for 13.10. And no if you edit an answer you don't get the bounty.

Also I voted to close that one as a duplicate of the other.